# How to link to another webpage using html/JS without keeping the filepath of the orginial page?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to go to stackoverflow.com for example when an ahref is clicked. The user types in the URLs so it could either have https:// at the start or not. Whenever the URL does have the https:// at the start, it works perfectly and links to the page, but whenever it doesn't. It keeps the file path, eg: file:///C:/Users/..../stackoverflow.com

How can I fix this? 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKZGdG

```js
    let results = document.getElementById('results');

    // let url = "https://www.facebook.com"; WORKS
    let name = "result";
    let url = "facebook.com";
    // this one leaves on the webite when Visit is clicked eg. file:///C:/User/../facebook.com
    //I want the user to be able use to fb.com or http://www.fb.com, how can I do this? 
  
    results.innerHTML += '<div class="card bg-light p-3">'+
                                        '<h3>'+name+ 
                                        ' <a class="btn btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="'+url+'">Visit</a> ' + 
                                        ' <a  onclick="delete(\''+url+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> ' +
                                        '</h3>' 
                                        + '</div>';
```

```html
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add // before your url. So in your case, this should work:

```
results.innerHTML += '<div class="card bg-light p-3">'+
                                        '<h3>'+name+ 
                                        ' <a class="btn btn-secondary" target="_blank" href="//'+url+'">Visit</a> ' + 
                                        ' <a  onclick="delete(\''+url+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> ' +
                                        '</h3>' 
                                        + '</div>';
```

This is because when you add a link without a protocol or a slash, it gets interpreted as a relative path.

Comment: What happens if `http(s)` is in the link?

Comment: You are right, I was inattentive. In this case, you should write a function that would check whether the user has entered a protocol. If yes, leave it as is, if not, add // to it so that protocol will be determined for you and you won't have the problem of the path

Comment: Works on the example but not my project, this change makes the path to "file:/// " if there is no https on the link and "file:///stackoverflow.com" if there is https. This makes neither one work.